# How to share project to Github via PyCharm such that it does not include .gitignore files

Tags: python, django, github, pycharm, gitignore

I cannot figure out how to share my PyCharm project with Github so that it does not include `.gitignore` files. I have read solutions from other posts, and tried them, and the problem persists.

What I've tried:

- Deleting the repository from Github:   #To start over
- Removing path to previously existing Github repo in PyCharm version:
  #To disconnect Pycharm GitHub connection
- `git remote remove origin`: #To remove all references to remote repo
- `git rm -r --cached .` : #To remove all files from git
- `git add .`: #To add files back to git *note: `.gitignore` already exists so this step is done after
- installed ignore
- Then, sharing with Github...

Yet it is still including files listed in `.gitignore`.  What am I doing wrong?

`.gitignore`

```
# Created by https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/python,django,intellij,macos
# Edit at https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore?templates=python,django,intellij,macos

### Django ###
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
__pycache__/
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
db.sqlite3-journal
media

# If your build process includes running collectstatic, then you probably don't need or want to include staticfiles/
# in your Git repository. Update and uncomment the following line accordingly.
# <django-project-name>/staticfiles/

### Django.Python Stack ###
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
*.py[cod]
*$py.class

# C extensions
*.so

# Distribution / packaging
.Python
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
downloads/
eggs/
.eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
wheels/
pip-wheel-metadata/
share/python-wheels/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
MANIFEST

# PyInstaller
#  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
#  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.
*.manifest
*.spec

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt
pip-delete-this-directory.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
htmlcov/
.tox/
.nox/
.coverage
.coverage.*
.cache
nosetests.xml
coverage.xml
*.cover
*.py,cover
.hypothesis/
.pytest_cache/
pytestdebug.log

# Translations
*.mo

# Django stuff:

# Flask stuff:
instance/
.webassets-cache

# Scrapy stuff:
.scrapy

# Sphinx documentation
docs/_build/
doc/_build/

# PyBuilder
target/

# Jupyter Notebook
.ipynb_checkpoints

# IPython
profile_default/
ipython_config.py

# pyenv
.python-version

# pipenv
#   According to pypa/pipenv#598, it is recommended to include Pipfile.lock in version control.
#   However, in case of collaboration, if having platform-specific dependencies or dependencies
#   having no cross-platform support, pipenv may install dependencies that don't work, or not
#   install all needed dependencies.
#Pipfile.lock

# PEP 582; used by e.g. github.com/David-OConnor/pyflow
__pypackages__/

# Celery stuff
celerybeat-schedule
celerybeat.pid

# SageMath parsed files
*.sage.py

# Environments
.env
.venv
env/
venv/
ENV/
env.bak/
venv.bak/
pythonenv*

# Spyder project settings
.spyderproject
.spyproject

# Rope project settings
.ropeproject

# mkdocs documentation
/site

# mypy
.mypy_cache/
.dmypy.json
dmypy.json

# Pyre type checker
.pyre/

# pytype static type analyzer
.pytype/

# profiling data
.prof

### Intellij ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio, WebStorm and Rider
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff
.idea/**/workspace.xml
.idea/**/tasks.xml
.idea/**/usage.statistics.xml
.idea/**/dictionaries
.idea/**/shelf

# Generated files
.idea/**/contentModel.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files
.idea/**/dataSources/
.idea/**/dataSources.ids
.idea/**/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/**/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/**/dynamic.xml
.idea/**/uiDesigner.xml
.idea/**/dbnavigator.xml

# Gradle
.idea/**/gradle.xml
.idea/**/libraries

# Gradle and Maven with auto-import
# When using Gradle or Maven with auto-import, you should exclude module files,
# since they will be recreated, and may cause churn.  Uncomment if using
# auto-import.
# .idea/artifacts
# .idea/compiler.xml
# .idea/jarRepositories.xml
# .idea/modules.xml
# .idea/*.iml
# .idea/modules
# *.iml
# *.ipr

# CMake
cmake-build-*/

# Mongo Explorer plugin
.idea/**/mongoSettings.xml

# File-based project format
*.iws

# IntelliJ
out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Cursive Clojure plugin
.idea/replstate.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

# Editor-based Rest Client
.idea/httpRequests

# Android studio 3.1+ serialized cache file
.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser

### Intellij Patch ###
# Comment Reason: https://github.com/joeblau/gitignore.io/issues/186#issuecomment-215987721

# *.iml
# modules.xml
# .idea/misc.xml
# *.ipr

# Sonarlint plugin
# https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint
.idea/**/sonarlint/

# SonarQube Plugin
# https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7238-sonarqube-community-plugin
.idea/**/sonarIssues.xml

# Markdown Navigator plugin
# https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7896-markdown-navigator-enhanced
.idea/**/markdown-navigator.xml
.idea/**/markdown-navigator-enh.xml
.idea/**/markdown-navigator/

# Cache file creation bug
# See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2257
.idea/$CACHE_FILE$

# CodeStream plugin
# https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12206-codestream
.idea/codestream.xml

### macOS ###
# General
.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns
.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk

### Python ###
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files

# C extensions

# Distribution / packaging

# PyInstaller
#  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
#  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.

# Installer logs

# Unit test / coverage reports

# Translations

# Django stuff:

# Flask stuff:

# Scrapy stuff:

# Sphinx documentation

# PyBuilder

# Jupyter Notebook

# IPython

# pyenv

# pipenv
#   According to pypa/pipenv#598, it is recommended to include Pipfile.lock in version control.
#   However, in case of collaboration, if having platform-specific dependencies or dependencies
#   having no cross-platform support, pipenv may install dependencies that don't work, or not
#   install all needed dependencies.

# PEP 582; used by e.g. github.com/David-OConnor/pyflow

# Celery stuff

# SageMath parsed files

# Environments

# Spyder project settings

# Rope project settings

# mkdocs documentation

# mypy

# Pyre type checker

# pytype static type analyzer

# profiling data

# End of https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/python,django,intellij,macos
```

[image: project file structure]

Comment: Can you include the contents of your .gitignore?

Comment: @AndreiTumbar Yes. Added it. Thanks.

Comment: Is `.gitignore` in the root of your directory i.e. where the repository is initialized? If yes, have you tried using the Git CLI and/or GitHub Desktop?

Comment: @DjangoDev1 Yes, I believe so. I added pic above of dir structure. So you are saying instead of going to ```VCS``` -> ```Import into Version Control``` -> ```Share Project on GitHub``` to push existing project to GitHub using Git CLI or GitHub Desktop?

Comment: Try it with the Git CLI by running `git add .` to add your files and see if the ones from `.gitignore` are added.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, but you indicate that you:

1. git add .
2. installed ignore
3. Then, sharing with Github...

If you truly are doing `git add .` *before* you create (and add) your `.gitignore` file, that could be your problem. Be sure you've created the .gitignore before you add any other files with `git add .` to ensure git excludes files as appropriate.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. I edited to clarify that I already had ```.gitignore``` file before doing ```git add . ```